# Getting the NUMPAD to work with VIM

Tags: linux, vim

how to Getting the NUMPAD to work with VIM ?

Comment: .​.​. W​h​a​t​?

Comment: how to use numpas keys in vim editor ?

Comment: Repeating the question explains nothing.

Comment: Do you want the numpad keys to input numbers in vim?  Or do you want them to work like arrow keys (and PgUp, Home, etc)?  Also, you need to tell us if you are using JUST vim, or also gvim.  Are you using vim within PuTTY or another terminal emulator?  As Ignacio said, your question needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using putty, you can try Terminal->Features->Disable Application Keypad Mode

Good luck!